# Can I cancel iOS local notification from the background?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipod

I have an app with scheduled notifications that need to be **cancelled after 5 minutes** if not interacted with.

In other words, a scheduled local notification is displayed (e.g. in lock screen), and if the user doesn't do anything (slide-to-read or go to the app), then call `cancelAllLocalNotifications`.

How would you attempt to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify scheduled notifications while your app is in the background.

> In other words, a scheduled local notification is displayed (e.g. in lock screen), and if the user doesn't do anything (slide-to-read or go to the app), then call `cancelAllLocalNotifications`.

If I understand you correctly, there should be no further notifications if the user doesn't do anything. And if the user launches your app again, there should be further notifications scheduled. The solution to this seems simple. Only schedule the one notification. If the user doesn't react to it, you don't have to cancel anything. If the user reacts, schedule the other notification(s) right when your app comes to the foreground.

Comment: Hi Ole, thanks for the response. Unfortunately, there needs to be several notifications scheduled. The user needs to be notified to do X at 1pm and Y at 2:30pm and Z at 3pm, but ONLY at those times (or within 5min of)... which is why I need to cancel any 'unused' notifications. - Again, thanks for your response!